# Color Space conversion problem on black image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am using python-opencv for simple conveniences like binarizing images and counting pixels.

There is a series of images captured from a camera, and some of them are completely black, and some have more information. For example:

[image: Black image] [image: Image with information]

The following code is loading the images:

```
    for img in file_list:
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()
        
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
```

I need to convert them to grayscale because I'm applying binarization and Otsu's thresholding.

The result of the previous code yields the following images (the first one corresponds to the left side of the example, and the other  corresponds to the right side):

[image: Black image result] [image: Result of the image with information]

So, if the problem was only with displaying the image, I would have no problems. But for pixel counting and binarization this is imposing a hurdle to my work. I tried other color spaces, but the same thing is happening. Any suggestions?

Btw, I'm developing this with jupyter-notebook and using py-opencv-3.4.2 and python 3.7.3 on conda 4.6.10. It does not seem to be a version problem since I also tried using [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com), and the same problem appears.

Comment: image is black. maybe **reality** was black? -- matplotlib stretches its values (probably 0-3 of 255), which is why you see that noisy picture. -- you have garbage data. what are you hoping to do with a black picture?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz like i said before, I have a bulk of images and need to process all of them because they're time related. I'll check if this stretching is happening and will come back soon. Thanks

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz that was exactly what was happenning. Matplotlib was stretching the values. I applied some simple logic and it's now solved. I am only wondering why matplotlib uses a different logic for 3 channel images and 1 channel images (maybe it interprets as bidimensional arrays?). Thank you so much.